# Nil value for a UIView within a View Controller even after presentViewController is called

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have a view controller, let's call it ParentViewController, that upon "viewDidAppear", does some calculations (doesn't matter what that is) and then if the answer is yes it calls the following function to show a modal popup:

```
func showAlert(title: String)
{
    let alertModal = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AlertController") as! AlertController
    alertModal.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext;
    self.presentViewController(alertModal, animated: true, completion: nil);
    alertModal.widget.title.text = title;
}
```

this line causes a problem:

```
alertModal.widget.title.text = title;
```

where it says `widget` is nil. This is bizarre because:

1. When the app first starts, and the ParentViewController's viewDidAppear gets called, this is fine...`widget` in this case isn't nil.
2. But when I go to ANOTHER view (call it SecondView) and then COME BACK to this view, suddenly the same method call results in the `widget` being nil and crashes the app.
3. I've researched other Stackoverflow questions and it appears the existing answer is to call "presentViewController" before trying to use the child view controller's components. But as noted in the code, this is already done, yet the child view controller's component, `widget`, was nil for some reason.
4. Note: the widget is declared as

   @IBOutlet weak var widget: AlertModal! // a reusable UIView

Comment: Does it help to move the `widget` access into the completion block that runs after presentation is finished?

Comment: @PhillipMills - huh, I didn't think of that! Let me try it tonight...

Comment: Perfect, it works!